# JSON Serializing in Django and JSON Parsing in Jquery

Tags: django, json, jquery

So I have this code:

```
def success_comment_post(request):
    if "c" in request.GET:
        c_id = request.GET["c"]
        comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=c_id)
        model = serializers.serialize("json", [comment])
        data = {'message': "Success message", 
                'message_type': 'success',
                'comment': model }
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, 'application/json')
        return response
    else:        
        data = {'message': "An error occured while adding the comment.", 
                'message_type': 'alert-danger'}
        response = JSONResponse(data, {}, 'application/json')
```

and back in jQuery I do the following:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    var comment = jQuery.parseJSON(data.comment)[0];
    addComment($("#comments"), comment);

 })
```

Now... in the Django function, why do I have to put the comment in **[]** --> 
**model = serializers.serialize("json", [comment])**

and back in jQuery, why do I have to do jQuery.parseJSON(data.comment)**[0]**?

Anyway I don't have to do this? I find it weird I have to hardcode the **[0]**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The data is coming out as an array, using [0] ensures you are reading the first element of the array

Comment: Anyways it doesn't come out of array? I am truly only passing one object.

Answer (score 0):

Well serializers.serialize only takes querysets or iterators with django model instances but using Comment.objects.get will return an object and not an iterator and that is why you will need to put it in [] to make it an iterator.

Since its a list you will have to access it like an array in javascript too. I would suggest not using serializer and using simplejson to convert field values to json.

Sample Code:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

comment = Comment.objects.get(pk=c_id)
data = {'message': "Success message", 
        'message_type': 'success',
        'comment': model_to_dict(comment)}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

I have only mentioned relevant parts of your code. Hopefully this should solve your problem